# Migrate to Chat option

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration, close-reasons, chat

How about for discussiony questions that come up on the main sites there could be a 'Migrate to Chat' close reason, and a room there to receive them?  Kind of like stackoverflowoverflow was, but triggered though a close-migration process.

The stub would just have to point to the room, since it's probably not easy to link to a specific place in chat.

We could call the room, the Question Graveyard.

This might help get rid of the Discussion pressure that new users keep bringing to bear.

Answer (score 1):

I would not like seeing questions being migrated to chat but if a question would be closed due to it's chatty nature, that suggesting the chat interface might not be a bad idea.

Comment: someone will suggest it in the comments

Comment: Stop chatting with me here, please use the chat system to do that!

Comment: How have you been?

Comment: It seems like if they're in their own room, then everyone who doesn't care about them can just avoid that room, as I plan on avoiding the _obscenities-r-us_ rooms.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is the right idea -- just because you ask a bad question doesn't mean you want a real-time discussion of the bad question, either.

Comment: I wasn't thinking so much about crappy questions, mostly about subjectivy/discussion ones.