# Should "move-to-chat" be provided on demand (as a button perhaps)?

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat, comment-to-chat-migration

When comments get too chatty the move-to-chat feature asks if you'd like to move it out. But this often happens after the fact and thus doesn't prevent it.

I propose that:

- Move-to-chat be provided as a button along side so that a user who knows their question or conversation may become drawn out may elect to *preempt* and take the conversation "off-line"

Comment: Newer, related request that builds on SE tooling that wasn't in place back in 2001: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288572/162102

Comment: Yes, I feel chat on the site is underutilized and would be of immense benefit.

Answer (score 72):

There is merit in this feature request. At least for Q&A based tech-support sites like Ask Ubuntu and Ask Different, where more often than not, we get troubleshooting type of questions. Because of the nature of the target audience, we assume that the user has none to limited knowledge.

Given this context, if a new user posts a question that requires a bit of to-and-fro communication, the comments aren't really effective in solving the problem. [And some of us think that the troubleshooting issues can be better handled if we could immediately bring users into chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4490595#4490595)

While chat requires a minimum 20 rep to use, I do realize that if you were to grant explicit write access to the user, we can sort that part out.

But, for that to happen rather seamlessly,  having a button in the question that invites the user as well as provides explicit write access by a click of a button would be rather handy.

[(Relevant part of our conversation regarding this issue)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/conversation/suggestions-to-make-troubleshooting-a-little-easier)

Comment: It is disappointing to see this suggestion has languished here for nearly 9 months. I don't want to isolate anyone in chat. But if things are getting chatty in the comments and you want to do something about it, there is currently no `easy` button I can push to request to move to chat. I had hoped that by now there would be.

Comment: It would also be useful for the "soft" Stacks (like SF&F, RPG, Writers, etc.) where there is a very high potential for comments to veer off into enjoyable tangents, not just on the trouble-shooting prone Stacks. (Right now, tangents just stay in comments and then make work for mods when the inevitable "too chatty" flags roll in.)

Comment: I came here from RPG, where a comment was posted explaining an edit, discussing answer formatting rules meta. When responding to that, I really wanted to be able to say "let's discuss this in chat...". Instead, the thread built in the comments, and I had to self-delete and flag their comments for deletion. :( Not great UX!

Answer (score 25):

Yes, there should be a discreet button to use at will to invite commentors to a chat.

The current heuristic often fails to intervene until after it's:

- too late to prevent chatty comments from accumulating
- too late for there to be any further discussion needed

I find I simply ignore the popup most of the time, since by the time it shows up, I'm done. It comes too late to serve as a reminder to avoid back-and-forth commenting, and often it only shows up when nothing more needs to be said.

A discreet button would serve as both reminder to avoid discussion in comments and as call-to-action to the alternative. Not to mention, automating the option earlier would make it more frequently chosen earlier — currently it can be done manually, but that is a high-barrier multi-step option that is not often remembered let alone chosen, compared to the low barrier of "just squeeze in one more comment."

Answer (score 21):

I wanted to propose it myself and I am glad that the question is being discussed already. I would like to add also that a possibility to say something "not to everybody" will solve the so long discussed problem of "excessive" thanks.

There is one more problem that will be solved this way: When a discussion appears not between 2, but among 3 people, and has many pure discussion messages, the existing automatics still will never propose to go into the chat mode.

As for the argument that we don't want people to send their unwanted messages to smb, here we are NOT talking about that.

1. The chat is not a personal message sent
2. I could start the chat not by sending a message, but by invitation to send messages to me. BTW, the existing form is something like that.

Comment: Requesting a way to send private messages has always been declined: see the FAQ, “[How do I contact other users?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/57537)”

Answer (score 19):

Yes, it should. This would particularly solve problems with sites like parenting, where soapboxing is common and we occasionally end up with very *BAD* advice given in comments where it can't be downvoted.

Answer (score 11):

Yes it should. I thought this was already a feature and wanted to do so today. I was just surprised that it is not.

In a bunch of (marked duplicate) questions/answers/comments about this, I keep seeing responses like "This is a great future feature" and then comments such as "Responding 4 years later... is the future here yet?" So here I am even years later after those types of comments; *what about now???* We are now, what, 7 years after this was first mentioned by the first question asking for this? Is it going to take a decade?

I am having a conversation that should not continue in comments and could get lengthy and "debaty". I just wanted to continue it offline from the comment area.

Comment: the average to get things implemented is 6 to 8. With just 7 past so far they are still good to meet the target deadline ...

Comment: @rene I assume that you are exaggerating; but whether you are or not, it seems ironic to me to think about the StackOverflow origins and about all the software engineering practices discussed on this website, and yet to have us complaining about things like this.

Comment: Well yes, the [6 to 8](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) isn't made up but the timescale is. There is a huge backlog of things to do and I'm sure this one isn't near the top on said list.

Comment: Well it should be on the top of the list because people are SPAMING the comments with irrelevant information. I guess they prefer to keep the comments because it's much better for SEO than an independent Chat window. honestly this is a feature that could be done in 5 minutes if they really wanted to, everything is already made, just need to add button to open the chat window (per answer/question)

Comment: "I'm sure this one isn't near the top on said list". Every time I see some news about a new thing being announced, I wonder how anyone involved could possibly have thought it more important than the various things about the software that vex me on a near-daily basis - such as this one.

Answer (score 5):

Back when this question was asked it was a bigger change.  Later some of the underlying tooling changed and I asked [this similar question (2016)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288572/162102) (which was, in turn, a refinement of a proposal from 2013).  I don't think that question is a dupe of this question because the answers here don't take into account the approach I proposed there, which is:

> Let's allow users at some moderately-low reputation level (1000?) to push a button that:
>
> - creates a chat room
> - grants access to that room to the post's author and everybody who's commented so far
> - copies all comments to the room
> - creates a comment on the post linking to the room

Now that moderators can move comments to chat (they couldn't when you asked this question), we're most of the way there. I see two remaining pieces of work:

- Create a user interface to trigger it.  Maybe we add a "start a chat" link next to "add comment", which is replaced with a link saying something like (e.g.) "visit chat room (47 messages, last update 12 min ago)" after somebody does that.  Maybe there's a better UI.
- Decide how this feature interacts with the mod move.  This is a problem with the two-users-chatting scenario now, too, but allowing users to proactively create chat rooms could increase the problem of forked conversations.  (See the linked post for more on this.)

Answer (score 4):

I wish to voice my support for this suggestion. I [ranted about the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355334/ability-to-take-comment-discussions-to-chat-is-extremely-undiscoverable-please) separately months ago, noting how many years it has been, and there has unsurprisingly been no action in those months either. It boggles my mind that the software doesn't make it easier to take discussions to chat while simultaneously seeing fit to scold people for not doing so. This is atrocious UI. Why even create a chat feature if you're going to treat it like this?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes in less popular SE or in technical related SE that requires more input from the OP there is only one person that comments and he/she is the only one that might answer the question, and in the comment section, it's just a discussion between the OP and the person that wants to answer which get's lengthy until finally after 7 comments it shows the:

> Let us continue this discussion in chat.

[image: discussion in comments then chat]

It seems that since this question was first asked in 2011, there is a new (marked duplicate) questions/answers/comments about this, so I hope that we look at this once again.

Answer (score 1):

No. It shouldn't be too easy to direct the conversation into a chat too early, because valuable arguments to the questions could be hidden in a separate chat. Most of the time it is preferable to have all related discussions in one place (the comments to the question).

And if it's really needed, there is a button at the bottom to create a new chat already.