# "move comments to chat" link disappeared

Tags: support, comments, chat, comment-to-chat-migration

I got a suggestion to "automatically move comments to chat", but I decided to post another comment first. However, once I did the link disappeared. How do I get it back?

Comment: After the disappearence, I and another user made around 10 comments. After that, for now, link seems to appear constantly. In case it disappear I shall comment here again. ( Still, I wonder, why to show such a link to user (i.e. me) and say "user1123502 has only 11 reputation, not yet enough to chat" after click on it. )

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100967

Comment: Some time link disappeared again, but immediatly appeared after web page reload (F5 button). Note: for the time of writing my original complain, I tried web page reload, and it did not help.