# Add option to invite users to chat from comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should “move-to-chat” be provided on demand (as a button perhaps)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100967/should-move-to-chat-be-provided-on-demand-as-a-button-perhaps)

I just found myself beginning to delve into a long comment thread over in Gaming.SE, where the comments have largely begun to drift away from the core question.

[Are there any usable non-player-owned bookshelves?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/47348/6274)

In such cases, I know there is a threshold past which the site will prompt you to move the discussion to chat.  However, I'd like to see options implemented that could facilitate this *without* the users having to wait (and meanwhile continue to generate more comment noise) for that threshold.

Options could be:

- Extra icon similar and/or near to the up-vote/flag icons, which performs the same function as existing "move to chat" functionality.
- Drop-down menu when clicking on commenter usernames, which includes "create chatroom" option.

Some restrictions to prevent abuse could be:

- User must have a certain reputation level.
- User must have already participated in the comment thread at least once.

Comment: `certain reputation level != restriction to prevent abuse`

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox Technically, you may be right.  However, I would still contend that it reduces the likelihood.