# Create chat from question

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should “move-to-chat” be provided on demand (as a button perhaps)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100967/should-move-to-chat-be-provided-on-demand-as-a-button-perhaps)

Is there a way to create a chat based on a question?  Basically I see a question that should be migrated to a chat room to figure out what the person is trying to accomplish, but can't find a way to do it.

I know that if "too many" chats happen it recommends it, but is there a way to programmatically do it ?