# Can I get a Continue Discussion In Chat button earlier?

Tags: feature-request

If a commenter says some fact that I don't entirely agree with, I tend to reply. Sometimes we do not immediately come to a consensus and I can tell it has a good chance of creating a long back-and-forth dialogue.

Could I request a way to quickly create a chat room to continue the discussion? (similar to the button that appears after the dialogue gets rather long)

I tried creating it manually once, but it is so tedious to go over there, enter a description, and then post a link back to the new chat room, on the original comment discussion.

Perhaps this Move To Chat button appears earlier only when I reach a certain level of reputation? IDK, but it would be nice to pre-emtively prevent cluttering of the comments trail.

Comment: I already upvoted this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100967/should-move-to-chat-be-provided-on-demand-as-a-button-perhaps, and I may have posted an exact duplicate.. Just wanted to bring a bit of added attention to the topic?