# Add a {Start a new}/{Join the} discussion on this {Question}/{Answer} button

Tags: discussion, comments, chat

There is a significant push back being felt as a result of the implementation of the Code of Conduct.

This is especially true for the crackdown on comments. I think that we can smooth this by adding a new button to Join or start discussion on any question or answer.

This will allow people to quickly join the discussion in chat rather than in comments.  Right now the only "easy" way to start a discussion is to post multiple comments.  If we make it easier to have a targeted discussion in chat then we should see less need or desire to chat in comments.

I suggest this because the customers of SE want to be able to have discussions on questions and answers.  There is already a method to do this.  I am just suggesting making it easier for those users to avail themselves of that method, as well as to corral that chatter to where it belongs.

Comment: *There is a significant push back being felt* that sounds as success to me. Why would you want to bring it back but now in chat that is even less capable of serious (self) moderation.

Comment: I support the idea, but not the reasoning. Unfortunately, there's already a [feature request on it from years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100967/should-move-to-chat-be-provided-on-demand-as-a-button-perhaps).

Comment: @NicolBolas - I have changed this to a discussion because I think the times had changed in the last few months.  If the community wants to close it as duplicate I can understand but I think there is value in rehashing this discussion.

Comment: @Chad: No, times really haven't changed. The stuff being gotten rid of was not productive discussion. We don't want it in chat any more than we wanted it in comments.

Comment: @NicolBolas - I dont want it either.  But there is a base of the SE customers that want that part of the Social media aspect.  You and I are not the only opinions that matter.

Comment: If I wanted that, I would use social media.  It's not like there is a shortage of choices.

Comment: @MartinJames - This is social media.  Just its own flavor.