# Can the chat message pop-up be inserted after 5 comment "back and forth" argument strategies?

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat, flags, moderator-tools

When users complain about a iffy post, they start suggesting edits and then another user gives an explanation on how that edit suggestion is wrong.

The users go back and forth, and then suddenly, when 8 - 12 comments are posted, a screen like this shows up:

> Comments aren't for extended discussion. Would you like to continue this conversation in **chat**?

That is after a long time and I am suggesting that relevantly after 5 comments, that message should appear. After you create a chat room from this link redirector, a bubble comment says to the other user:

> Let us continue this **discussion in chat.**

I don't know if a moderator/community bot suspected the "back and forth" movement and inserted that message, but I know that it should be at least after 5 or 6 comments that it should pop up without any online supervision. Can this happen, or what are some ways I can be effective to comment arguments with comments?

**Should I:**

- Flag 1 comment out of the bunch for a moderator to view the posts?
- Allow another moderator/community bot to insert the message (if they do)
- Comment that they shouldn't be fighting and/or say that they should **continue it in chat myself?**

Comment: On what site specifically? I can say for certain this wouldn't be appropriate on worldbuilding, often long explanations are required to get the many points across. I've seen a single comment spanning four posted comments because of the level of detail involved, so what sites do you think your strategy might be appropriate to? Why aren't you posting this on their metas?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100967/334566 and the links therein. Those questions mainly focus on having some way of manually speeding up the continue-in-chat feature, which is a bit different to your suggestion of tweaking the algorithm so it happens sooner.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. this is one of the "just saying" posts, and this post is proclaimed not a duplicate.

Comment: @loan_2314 Then maybe there should be a [tag:just-saying] tag, so people don't devalue the [tag:feature-request] tag. I'm up for that.

Comment: May you please create the tag? As you can see, I have less than 300 reputation. @ARogueAnt.

Comment: @loan_2314 I've just tried, it's easy on my favorite site but it's not obvious here. Looking up [the requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/when-should-i-create-a-new-tag-how-do-i-request-a-new-tag-if-i-dont-have-enoug), it's not so obvious that there's a need. It seemed like some kind of surreal fun in conception though.

Comment: I do not see the tag that you said you have created for my post. @ARogueAnt.

Comment: The comments we are posting are being a relation to my post.

Comment: I've not created one, please re-read my previous comments for clarification. Humor and tone are difficult to get across in this form, but I was joking, because this question seems to lack context, research and understanding of the variety of sites on the network and their varying requirements.  @loan_2314