# Live refresh on the Moderator Elections page

Tags: feature-request, election, live-refresh

The [elections page](https://stackoverflow.com/election) is one of those areas of the site that don't get much traffic (if at all) on a regular basis. However during elections, these pages receive a large amount of traffic in a relatively short period of time. Along with this traffic comes, by *any* Stack Overflow definition, a






<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>r</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>     











<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>r</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>       









<sup><sup><sup><sup>r</sup></sup></sup></sup>          







<sup><sup><sup>r</sup></sup></sup>                           





<sup><sup>r</sup></sup>                            



<sup>r</sup>                                   

really long comment section for almost each nomination.  Don't get me wrong; This is all well and good. Voters and candidates should definitely have the opportunity to openly discuss each others' nominations and voting considerations.

We've all been thinking it, so I'll just put it out there.

Can we please upgrade the election pages to include the [live-refresh](/questions/tagged/live-refresh) feature? If it's considered a good idea then it should be implemented on the elections page where comments are [encouraged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQn8e.png).

Comment: My name is jadarnel27, and I approve this message.  (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Moderator nominations should use comments to clarify positions and intents, not to carry out long and deliberate conversations. If you're editing that much of your original post that people continuously need to ask where you stand on a topic, are you sure that your original mod bid was sufficiently well crafted?

Otherwise, it sounds like something that would be better reserved for chat, and less for comments. a-la:

> [Provide a tool for moderators to migrate comments to chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93444/provide-a-tool-for-moderators-to-migrate-comments-to-chat)

Comment: I disagree. "*If you're editing that much of your original post that people continuously need to ask where you stand on a topic,*" - This is not about editing the post. The feature request was to auto-load the comments on the /election/ page. Plus, there is a 1200 character limit for nominations, so everything you want to say can't be included in the nomination text itself. To answer the questions put forward by the users, you *will* at some point have to use comments.