# Convert a chain of comments into a Chat?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat, moderator-tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Provide a tool for moderators to migrate comments to chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93444/provide-a-tool-for-moderators-to-migrate-comments-to-chat)

- As a moderator do I have a way to convert a chain of comments between two or more participants, not including myself, into a chat room?
- If not, should moderators have this function?

I find that interesting questions often spawn a lot of comments forming an ad hoc discussion.  These are discouraged, yet the interaction is often quite informative.  It seems to me that converting these comments into a Chat would be superior to the alternatives I am aware of.

Comment: It seems that feature has already been requested: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93444/provide-a-tool-for-moderators-to-migrate-comments-to-chat?rq=1