# Provide a tool to quickly convert comments to an edit

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, edits, moderator-tools

In reference to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144628/why-was-this-question-locked/) that illustrates something I encounter a lot, I'd like moderators to have the ability to convert comments to edits.

Here's why:

Often times I get a notice in the moderator panel that tells me a question has more than 20 comments in it.

This [answer is a recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092399/convert-stored-procedure-to-linq/12092749#12092749):

[image: Too many comments]

There are lots of comments in here that I just want to purge. They don't add anything, and they detract from a user visiting the page from being able to follow what's going on.

In short, they make the experience *sub-optimal*.

But there are comments that should be edits to the question, for example, this comment:

[image: comment convert to edit on question]

And there are some comments that should be converted to edits on the answer, for example:

[image]

But as a Moderator, I have to individually select which comments to keep, and I have to *manually edit the question or answer* to put those comments in if they are useful.  Or, I can just purge all the comments, but that's the nuclear option.

#### Possible solutions:

1. Make a popup when the asker posts a comment asking them if they should make this an edit instead. "Does this comment contain information about your problem? If so, make it an edit instead."  Maybe it can automatically make it an 'edit' if they hit 'yes' to that dialog. (I'm not a fan of this approach, but I'm throwing it out there for feedback.
2. Allow moderators to have a `Convert to Edit` ability inline on comments. A one-click deal (or at most, two clicks) so we can quickly cull comments and separate the wheat from the chaff.  The system should be smart enough (I'm good with 80% correct) to know that when the asker posts a comment and a moderator converts it to an edit, that it should go on the question. Same with when the answerer posts a comment.

What are your thoughts on these feature requests, and do you believe this could be done another way?

Comment: RE solution 1: It looks like you're trying to clarify your question. Would you like help?

Comment: Haha, funny this, because I've often wanted the opposite functionality: whenever I see suggested edits which contain (potentially valid) modifications to code, I reject them and then add a comment for the OP, so that they can decide whether they want to integrate it into their post.

Comment: @benjol I think we're talking about two different things. I'm only referring to comments made by the OP or the answerer, not comments made by the answerer on the OP's question post.

Comment: OK, I see. So even if the OP comments on an answer, the edit goes to the question? But for the answerer it only applies on their own answer?

Comment: +1 This seems to be more humane than auto deletion.