# what to do if an answer has too many "Thanks!" comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags, comment-flags

First off, this doesn't apply to ['ordinary comments'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144694/as-a-10k-user-what-should-i-do-with-the-too-many-comments-flag).

Should I flag a question that has too many `thanks! this worked for me` comments? i.e. If there are about 30 comments in total but I have to sift through half of them to find actual *comments* on the answer.

Comment: You can flag all of them as "noise".

Comment: @Mysticial should i choose `not constructive / off-topic` or `too chatty` or `obsolete` or `other` and write 'noise'?

Comment: I'd go with "chatty". But I don't think it matters. A quick glance by a mod and it'll be clear that it can be deleted.

Comment: Though sometimes I prefer to keep some of these "thanks!" comments - especially if they're heavily upvoted and towards the bottom of the list. They serve as somewhat of an explicit confirmation that the answer works.

Comment: Very good point...but then again, if an answer has 500 upvotes, it carries more weight than 100 thanks IMO and you don't have to click 'more comments' to notice that. All the thanks comments just clutter up the actual discussion going on. But I totally agree, some thanks are useful and other are hilarious!

Comment: Answers with 500 upvotes will usually generate a lot of useless comments regardless. They usually come in two flavors: "Thanks!" or "This is awesome!!!". Or, "WTF?!?! 500 votes for this?!?! Come on...".

Comment: hahah very true...the site would be a lot more boring without them...but its the ones that are just 'thanks!' that are a waste of eyeball movement to read them...i wonder if anyone's discussed automatically blocking  the exact string `'thanks!'`?

Comment: No!! I have one answer with a few `thanks` comments after it, for some of them the thanks is worth more than the upvote because it shows how much my answer helped them, which makes me happy. Flag everyone else's excessive thanks comments, don't take mine :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess I'll turn the comments into an answer:

You can flag such comments as "too chatty" - since, as you have described, they're getting in the way of the "real" comments.

Personally, I prefer to keep *some* of these comments. (especially the funny and/or highly upvoted ones) They serve as an explicit indicator that the answer either works, or is awesome in some way.

But if half the comments are filled with them, then flag away.