# Should comments like "I love this post" be flagged?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

Recently, I had flagged a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349555/a-yaakov-ellis-inspired-meta-se-poetry-contest-write-poems-win-rep#comment1170891_349563) which said:

> This one is my favorite.

I had flagged it as "**No longer needed**" because I thought that it was a type of "compliment" (not that I am against that post, I love that too) and in the Help section it is mentioned that comments should not be added if they are

> **Compliments** which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!");
> instead, upvote it and pay it forward;

But my flag was declined. Thus, I want to know that are comments like "I love this post" not considered as compliments and should not be flagged?

Comment: Rules on meta are more relaxed than on main. And the comment is gone now, FWIW

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279449/should-1-and-thanks-comments-be-a-declined-flag

Comment: I think you should flag the comment when it says you like this question, but if they say that it is a useful question you shouldn't flag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that any comment that simply states:

> This one is my favorite

appears to be trying to promote an answer (or question) above others by enticing other users to vote for it.

If someone thinks a post is useful, even their favorite of all time, then they should upvote it. If others are of a like mind then they should do the same independently. It is only the content of the post, not who made it, or who likes it, that should sway the voting on it.

I think you were right to flag a comment like this on any post, Meta or Main, at any time you saw it.

Answer (score 13):

Depends a bit on the context.

Glorfindel makes a good point in [his answer about 'thanks, done, edited' comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349618/369802) too:

> There's one caveat: the 'Done' comment might ping the author of the first comment (either directly, or because the only comments are by the author of the post and the author of the first comment); if the comment is deleted before they visit the site again, they might miss the inbox notification. So it's probably better not to flag 'Done' comments too soon after they're created; not everybody is using the new Follow Posts feature.

If I look at the timeline, the comment was posted 23 hours ago, flagged 21 hours ago and I cleared the flag 20 hours ago: Just 3 hours after the comment was posted, which is a rather short time. This was also my main reason to decline the flag: A comment barely 3 hours old might not have been seen and appreciated yet.

Besides that, this comment is made on a answer to a post tagged fun. I'd argue fun is fun, but also falls out of 'usual' quality guidelines like 'compliments that don't add new information', because fun in itself isn't focused on adding new information. So, let's have a bit of fun, and let people say stuff like this. It's quite usual to see remarks like that on fun posts, and I tend to be lenient with them because they're nice and fun, exactly what the post is for.

I would recommend letting fun be fun, and use flags for when fun becomes not fun, instead of using them to lessen fun. Because it's never fun to handle flags asking you to delete fun.

Comment: +fun for so much fun

Comment: (*fun* intended)

Comment: A missed poem oppertunity

Comment: @Luuklag I couldn't thing of something funny to rhyme with fun.

Comment: Flagging a comment like this under a post tagged fun, is this a pun?

Comment: @Luuklag it has a tone of accusation. It hurts that when you try to make this community better, instead of being encouraged, you are frowned upon.

Comment: @GarimanSingh that depends on your definition of better, and whether or not that definition is aligned with the communities definition.

Comment: @Luuklag, my definition of better, is the same as that of the community, which encourages flagging to remove redundant posts and comments. It is then up to the moderator to decide if the flag is appropriate or not and they having conveyed their decision, I don't think it is beneficial to stretch this discussion further.

Comment: @Gariman It's a bit weird to say 'it is the same as that of the community', because *this particular community* has these poetry contests, winterbash contests/sharing, a q/a on meta memes, it used to have swag posts as well. And if you go looking at old posts, the community definitely encouraged some fun in comments as well. I appreciate many of your flags, and at any other site, I'd have deleted the comment you flagged without hesitation.

Comment: That said,  hunting down every old comment thanking someone or otherwise being pleasant doesn't make the community that much better, as it only balances what's left more towards being unpleasant. I do hope to convey to you that Meta SE has a particular definition of 'better', and while we hold posts here to a certain quality standard, it's important to keep that other definition of 'better' in mind too, and perhaps focus your efforts elsewhere than flagging politeness as no longer needed, especially if it's not drowning out important information.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell, I realise your point. But I feel one should tell the other politely (as you did) instead of accusing the other when one knows that the other was trying to help.