# Room for mod-migrated comments has wrong users

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, moderator-tools, user-accounts

[As of recently, mods can move excessive comments to a chatroom via the flag.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237976/166155)

However, the comment participants are not given write access to the room. Rather the users with the chat-user-number equal to the participants site-user-number are given access. This is clearly an error.

[Example](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/16792/discussion-on-question-by-isaac-moses-whats-a-good-website-for-asking-questions?tab=access)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it also registered as activity for those chat-user-number users in their last seen info on their global account info.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The wrong userId was being passed to the process to give explicit access to a room. It was the Id of the site user rather than the chat user, as it should have been.

This is now fixed and deployed.