# Error in generated comment when using the tool: Move comments to chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, moderator-tools, automatic-comments

I used the moderator tool [**Move comments to chat**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237976/158428) for the first time today, on [Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com), and the comment that was created did not work properly.  The comment that was created:

```
Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been <a href="http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17535/discussion-on-question-by-igor-rivin-a-more-perfect-union">moved to chat</a>.
```

[image]

Additional examples from other users:

[image: http://static.ellipsix.net/ext-tmp/chatcomment.png]

[image: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240334]

Not only does the link appear malformed but it is also broken.  Note that the `<a href=` form is used rather than the `[name](url)` markdown that works in comments.  I had to edit the comment to correct the problem.

Comment: Happened recently on [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71171/is-there-anything-preventing-the-nsa-from-becoming-a-root-ca#comment116441_71174)

Comment: Thanks for the bounty @Yannis

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This bug report fell through the cracks, sorry that this took so long. It's fixed in the next build.

The comment text was accidentally converted to HTML by our translation engine (which accepts MarkdownMini); while that's usually the correct behavior, in this case it was supposed to actually return Markdown, and only rendering of the comment should then turn it into HTML.

Comment: I wish I could +100 this because this was a giant pain in my blue feet!!

Comment: @bluefeet but you can!

Comment: _grumble, grumble_ @ShadowWizard