# Auto-generated "Comments moved to chat" comment uses HTML instead of Markdown, causing the link to appear broken

Tags: bug, comments, chat, moderator-tools

I just tried moving some comments to chat; however, the link to the chat room appears to be broken:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/rooms/17543/discussion-on-question-by-kostja-how-can-i-ask-a-potential-employer-to-show-prod%22%3Emoved

It turns out the link isn't *really* broken; instead, the auto-generated comment uses HTML anchor tags instead of Markdown. I edited the comment so the link isn't broken. Here is the original:

```
Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has 
been <a href="https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17543/discussion-on-question-by-kostja-how-can-i-ask-a-potential-employer-to-show-prod">moved to chat</a>.
```

Here's a screenshot of what the comment looked like:

[image: Screenshot of bad chat comment]

Here's the link to the question where the problem occurred:  [How can I ask a potential employer to show production code?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/34126/how-can-i-ask-a-potential-employer-to-show-production-code)

Comment: Does this button work now? It stopped working a while ago but I never bothered to report it...

Comment: @enderland - yep. works but needs some TLC.